# Cambiar el contenido de un div usando un select

Tags: javascript, html

¿Cómo cambiar contenido de un div usando un select?

Tengo un `div` con dos imágenes que quiero que al seleccionar un elemento del `select` cambien las dos imágenes del div por otras dos, o por una. No recuerdo cómo hacerlo o simplemente no sé.

Comment: Hola Antonio, lee [ask] en el centro de ayuda y dale a [edit] tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. Por ejemplo: ¿qué has buscado sobre el tema? (creo que hay varias preguntas en el sitio que te pueden servir de ayuda) ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento? ¿Con qué errores/dificultades te estás encontrando? ¿Usas alguna biblioteca JS o lo quieres en JavaScript puro?

Answer (score 1):

Esto podría ser un ejemplo en javascript básico de lo que buscas y que puedes moldear adaptandolo a tus necesidades.

```js
document.getElementById('miSelect').onchange = function(event){  
  document.getElementById('miImagen').src = document.getElementById('miSelect').value;
}
```

```css
img{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img id="miImagen" src="http://support.yumpu.com/en/wp-content/themes/qaengine/img/default-thumbnail.jpg">
<select id="miSelect">
  <option value="http://support.yumpu.com/en/wp-content/themes/qaengine/img/default-thumbnail.jpg" selected>Sin imagen</option>
  <option value="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/723561620761391104/BQmg7aTz_400x400.jpg">Imagen 1</option>
  <option value="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/v/N/K/k/N/3/number-2-design-md.png">Imagen 2</option>
</select>
```